# Remove Items From End Of Container With JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a feed of items coming into a list using the prepend method. I've been searching but can't find a method to remove X number of items from the end - to prevent it overflowing.

How do I remove the last 3 elements from this list using jquery?

```
<div id="feed">
<ul>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`.slice()` method](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to remove the last three elements from the jQuery object:

```
$('#feed li').slice(-3).remove();
```

Snippet:

```js
$('#feed li').slice(-3).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="feed">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
    <li class="item">5</li>
    <li class="item">6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use the jQuery [`:gt()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and specify a negative number for the index. Keep in mind that the index for this selector is zero-based, which means that `-4` would be used to remove the last three elements.

```
$('#feed li:gt(-4)').remove();
```

Snippet:

```js
$('#feed li:gt(-4)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="feed">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
    <li class="item">5</li>
    <li class="item">6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: $( "li" ).slice(-3).remove(); it work great i create a jsfiddle ; https://jsfiddle.net/f0cuocmg/

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi - Yep, I included example snippets above.

Comment: If you can only have so many in the list, you could do `$('#feed > ul > li:gt(4)').remove();` instead to keep the same number of items in the list (and remove any after the fifth index, for instance). Of course, no idea if that's relevant for the OP, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/rewn0o5y/